# ancestor element from span element in python via selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get where first `<tr>` ancestor node is from  `<span>` node.
`<span>` node is child of `<div>` which is also a `<td>` element child. I get to the value of `<span>` by finding_element with `myList[1]` element search. I need to get to first `<tr>` element.

I looked for getting ancestor nodes via XPATH. But none of them work correctly.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
url = 'https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1'
driver.get(url)

myList=[]
myList.append(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")))
for element in elements:
    myList.append(element.text)


driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
element_to_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, myList[1])))
classes = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..")
print("-works well")
print(classes.get_attribute("class"))
class_parent_tr = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span/ancestor::tr")#need to get <tr
print("--")
print(class_parent_tr.get_attribute("class"))
class_parent_tr_02 = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[text()='Golden State Warriors']]")#need to get from here to node<tr. I took the text from a list myList[1], and wrote it as a text
print("---")
print(class_parent_tr_02.get_attribute("class"))
result=class_parent_tr.find_element(By.XPATH("//td[6]"))#
print(result.text)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath you can locate parent element based on child element.
Especially since here you are going to locate a `tr` element based on text content of some of it's child elements.
All what you need here is as following:

```py
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
xpath_template = "//tr[contains(.,'{0}')]"
xpath = xpath_template.format(myList[1])
tr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

`xpath` here is a XPath expression dynamically built based on the text contained in `myList[1]`
The actual value of `xpath` is `"//tr[contains(.,'Golden State Warriors')]"`
`tr` is getting the desired element on the page.
**UPD**
This is my code:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1'
driver.get(url)

myList=[]
myList.append(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")))
for element in elements:
    myList.append(element.text)


driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
xpath_template = "//tr[contains(.,'{0}')]"
xpath = xpath_template.format(myList[1])
tr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
text_content = tr.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td[6]").text
print(text_content)
```

And this is the output

```
.646
```

To get the 6-th `td` inside the `tr` you need to use the dot `.` infront of the XPath expression. Otherwise it will search from the top of the page.

Comment: But it does not give me result from `result=tr.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[6]")
print(result.text)`

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Genius..saviour..with one word.Thanks a lot

Comment: No, just some experience with Selenium and Xpath :)